# How to reload content of an article when redirected to it through AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, django, function, angularjs, controller

I'm using Django and AngularJS for a project of mine and when I update an article, I have set it to redirect to `this` article (that is - on form submit). Problem is - even though everything updates fine in the backend, it doesn't do the same on the frontend. If I hit `f5` (refresh) on my browser, I get the new info, if I don't, the content still stays the same.

**Update Controller**

```
var EditCtrl = function($scope, $stateParams, $http, Revision, $location) {

    $http.get('http://api.local/api/v1/articlerevision/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.revision = data;
    });


    $scope.update = function() {
        Revision.update($scope.revision);
        $location.path('/wiki/revision/'+$stateParams.id);
    };

};
```

**View Controller**

```
var ViewCtrl = function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
    $http.get('http://api.local/api/v1/articlerevision/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.revision = data;
    });

    $scope.toggle = false;
    $scope.comments = false;
};
```

Is there some kind of a refresh command that I could place inside of the view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a syncronization problem: you update isn't finished yet when you redirect to the revision view.

Try change to something like that:

```
var EditCtrl = function($scope, $stateParams, $http, Revision, $location) {

    $http.get('http://api.local/api/v1/articlerevision/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(data) {
        $scope.revision = data;
    });


    $scope.update = function() {
        Revision.update($scope.revision, /* success */ function(data) {
            $location.path('/wiki/revision/'+$stateParams.id);
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a issue due to async nature of the call. Your Edit Controller seems to be making 2 async calls

```
$http.get('http://api.local/api/v1/articlerevision/' + $stateParams.id).success(function(data) {
    $scope.revision = data;
});   //This call is async


$scope.update = function() {
    Revision.update($scope.revision);  //Is this async?
    $location.path('/wiki/revision/'+$stateParams.id);  //Does this navigation happen before update is complete?
};
```